# How to get the max of a table and corresponding attribute with one request in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table 
M

```
price1  name             price2
--------------------------------
88      astérix          80
75      cetautomatix     70
95      panoramix        90
20      assurancetourix  30
105     NULL             NULL
```

And I want to get the max of price2 with corresponding name and price1

So the result I want would be

```
price1  name             price2
--------------------------------
95      panoramix        90
```

I know that a lot of pretty similar question were asked here and I achieved to find this solution.

```
SELECT m.price1, m.nom, m.price2
FROM M m
WHERE m.price2 = (SELECT MAX(m.price2) FROM M m);
```

However I'd like to find a solution where I need only one request (Just one SELECT, not two)

So I tried things like that

```
SELECT m.price1, m.nom, MAX(m.price2)
FROM M m
Group by m.nom, m.price1
```

But it doesn't work like i want.

So if someone know a way to do it in only one request it would be really helpfull!

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
select max(price1) keep (dense_rank first order by price2 desc nulls last) as price1,
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by price2 desc nulls last) as name,
       max(price2)
from m;
```

This is not exactly the same as your query.  This always returns one row.  In the event of ties, the `price1` and `name` might come from different rows.

In Oracle 12C, you could do:

```
select m.*
from m
order by price2 desc nulls last
fetch first 1 row only;
```

However, your method with the subquery is perhaps the most efficient way to write the query, if you have an index on `m(price2)`.

Comment: You probably meant `order by price2 desc`

Comment: Ditto. My answer. `order by price2 desc nulls last` will achive this. :)

Comment: Similarly you have to add `nulls last` inside the window function in first query as well. :)

Comment: If I add the `nulls last ` the first solution works perfectly. As soon as you update your post with this correction I will accept your answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

12c Solution:

```
SELECT M.*
       FROM M
   ORDER BY price2 DESC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

For earlier versions, it would be easy if you use multiple selects.